# How can I set up a VPN connection on my Nexus One?

Tags: nexus-one, email, settings, vpn, exchange

I often check my mail at my office using the VPN connection which bridged my PC with the Microsoft Exchange Server and so that I can check mail using Outlook.

I want to do the same thing when I'm out of my office and on my Nexus One mobile phone. But I don't know how to set up a VPN connection like the way I do it on my PC.

Below is the screenshot of how I set up my VPN on my PC. Please share if you know a solution for me. All helps are welcome and very much appriciated!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about older versions of Android, but from my 2.1 version it is pretty straight-forward. From the Home screen go to Settings and tap "Wireless and Networks." Then "VPN Settings" and Add VPN and follow the prompts from there.

Comment: I asked because the N1 show up 4 options (PPTP, L2TP, L2TP/IPSec PSK, L2TP/IPSec CRT) and I have no idea what they are. The information I give to Windows 7 for a VPN connection is just the server IP and my user/password.

Comment: Though, I tried the 1st one (PPTP) fill in my user/pass/server and it is connected now. Thanks

Comment: My next question is about setting up the email. I asked here http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2206/how-can-i-set-up-an-microsoft-exchange-email-on-my-nexus-one. Please visit if you know how-to.