# How can I set up an Microsoft Exchange email on my Nexus One?

Tags: nexus-one, email, settings, exchange, vpn

I often check my mail at my office using the VPN connection which bridged my PC with the Microsoft Exchange Server and so that I can check mail using Outlook.

I want to do the same thing when I'm out of my office and on my Nexus One mobile phone. I have succeeded in setting up the VPN connection (see details [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-set-up-a-vpn-connection-on-my-nexus-one)). But I cannot succeed in setting up my email on the phone.

Steps I have made:

1. Open my phoen (Nexus One)
2. Connect to VPN
3. Open `Email` application
4. Enter the email & password
5. Select Miscrosoft Exchange ActiveSync
6. Enter domain\username, password, and server
7. Any other options are left as-is ('User SSL' checked, 'Accept all cert' unchecked)
8. Failed :)

The information I entered are exactly all the same as what I use in Outlook, i.e. the email/password, then the domain\user, pass and server for Ms Exchange. But the connection to the server failed on my N1 - it says *"Setup not finish. Unable to open connection to server due to security error"*.

Have you ever succeeded? If so, please share. Your help are very much helpful & appreciated to me!

Answer (score 2):

After a while trying, I try to check the 'Accept all certification in step 7, and it works.